# div.getelementbyid(id).innerHTML = "" giving out error

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am facing an issue while setting the innerHTML of a div element to "". The element does exist when i first load it.[image]

I use a drop down on my HTML page. On change in option i want to clear all the contents and replace it with new SVG elements.

**Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**
I understand that the error is thrown because the Element it tries to retrieve is not found. 
My question is: After initial load of the page, the element is created and the element "movieNetwork" has contents within it.
But when i a run the code to clear the innerHTML on change in dropdown options, it gives out **Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null** error

Kindly let me know what might be the issue.
The below is the code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Customer Network</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="movie-network.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="popcha.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="movie-network.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="movieJson.js"></script> 
    <script>
      // Sniff MSIE version
      // http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/detect-ie-in-js-using-conditional-comments/
      var ie = ( function() {
        var undef,
        v = 3,
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');
        while (
         div.innerHTML='<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',all[0]
        );
        return v > 4 ? v : undef;
      }() );

      function takeAction() {
        if( ie && ie < 9 ) {
      D3notok();
        } else {
          // Load D3.js, and once loaded do our stuff
          var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = "d3.v3.min.js";
          script.addEventListener('load', D3ok, false);
          script.onload = "D3ok();";
      head.appendChild(script);
       }
     }

    </script>

</head>
<body onload="takeAction();">
    <div id ="selectoptionsMenu">
        <select id="selectoption" onchange="changeGraph()">
          <option value="eigen">Eigen Betweeness Centrality</option>
          <option value="central">Eigen Centrality</option>
          <option value="cluster">Cluster</option>
          <option value="transaction">Transaction</option>
          <option value="transaction">MediaSweep</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  <div id="nocontent">
    <h1>Sadly your browser is not compatible with this site</h1>

    <div>You can use <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">Google
    Chrome</a>, <a href="http://www.mozilla.org/firefox">Mozilla Firefox</a>
    or <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie">Microsoft
    Internet Explorer (v9 or above)</a> to access the PopCha Movie
    Network</div>

  </div>

  <div id="movieNetwork"></div>
  <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeGraph()
         {  
            document.getElementById(movieNetwork).innerHTML = ""; //ERROR
            D3ok();

         }
         </script>
     </div>
  <div id="sidepanel">
    <div id="title">
        <br/>Customer Network<br/>
    </div>    
    <div id="movieInfo" class="panel_off"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How you set values to `movieNetwork`? @maverick

Comment: Nin-ya .. stupid mistake from my side. Sorry for that. Forgot to include the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to pass the id of the element to `document.getElementById()`, but you are passing a dom element reference(Since `movieNetwork` is the id of the element that gets [copied as a property of the window object](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)) so even if you have not declared `movieNetwork` that is referring to a dom element reference.

In your case you need to pass a string literal like

```
document.getElementById('movieNetwork')
```

Or in html5 browsers you could just say

```
movieNetwork.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you've written this line:

```
document.getElementById(movieNetwork).innerHTML = ""; //ERROR
```

... which is referencing a `movieNetwork` variable you never declared. So you're calling `document.getElementById(undefined)`, which returns null, then effectively writing `null.innerHTML = "";`. Hence your *Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null* error.

You probably need quotes around it:

```
document.getElementById("movieNetwork").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Thanks doppelgreener for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add quotes to the value in your `getElementByID`

change it to:

```
document.getElementById("movieNetwork").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Thanks Meaty McDuff for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok i did one hell of a stupid mistake.
I forgot the quotes and started looking at other section of the code for errors
document.getElementById("movieNetwork").innerHTML = "";

Should start listening to my dad and start wearing those glasses. Thank you guys for such a quick reply :)

Answer (score 0):

movieNetwork should be a string. As `movieNetwork` is undefined, `document.getElementById(movieNetwork)` will just return `null`.

Working code:

```
function changeGraph()
{   
    // Changed movieNetwork to "movieNetwork".
    document.getElementById("movieNetwork").innerHTML = "";
    D3ok();
}
```

Note that the argument passed into `document.getElementById()` should *always* be a string.

Comment: Thanks Grandon for the quick response :)